# UIKIT 3 get the name of the file been uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, uikit, getuikit

I try to create a function where the user uploads the file and then showing the image that's been uploaded to a div. But I need to have the name of the file in order to add the src attr to

Seems like UIKIT 3 does not have a way where I can get the name of the file when it's dropped or selected.

Anyone can help this, please?

Here's the code from UIKIT, and [here](https://getuikit.com/docs/upload)'s the docs they provide

```
               UIkit.upload('.js-upload', {

                    url: '../config/forms.php',

                    beforeSend: function () {
                        console.log('beforeSend', arguments);

                    },
                    beforeAll: function () {
                        console.log('beforeAll', arguments);
                    },
                    load: function () {
                        console.log('load', arguments);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('error', arguments);
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        console.log('complete', arguments);
                    },

                    loadStart: function (e) {
                        console.log('loadStart', arguments);

                        bar.removeAttribute('hidden');
                        bar.max = e.total;
                        bar.value = e.loaded;
                    },

                    progress: function (e) {
                        console.log('progress', arguments);

                        bar.max = e.total;
                        bar.value = e.loaded;
                    },

                    loadEnd: function (e) {
                        console.log('loadEnd', arguments);

                        bar.max = e.total;
                        bar.value = e.loaded;
                    },

                    completeAll: function (arguments) {

                        console.log('completeAll', arguments);

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            bar.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
                        }, 1000);

                    }

                });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") should include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIkit uploader: Getting the uploaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405171/uikit-uploader-getting-the-uploaded-file)

Answer (score 1):

JS side:

```
                        UIkit.upload('.js-upload', {

                            url: 'file_upload.php',
                            multiple: false,
                            mime: "image/*",

                            completeAll: function () {
                                uploaded_filename = arguments[0].response;
                            }

                        });
```

PHP Side:

```
$uploads_dir = PUBLIC_FOLDER."uploads"; 
$tmp_name = $_FILES['form-drop-place']['tmp_name'];
$image_name = $_FILES['form-drop-place']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$new_name = "newname." . $ext;
$new_place = $uploads_dir . "/" . $new_name;

if ( move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $new_place) ) {
    die($new_name);
} else {
    die();
}
```